# PHP: Increment variable on date change

Tags: php, loops, date

I'm building a class-schedule tool, where users can upload a .csv-file. I want to keep track of the dates with a variable so users can upload a schedule, which starts on the 15th of a month, for example. Therefore, I would like to increment a variable on date change. The data I receive from the csv looks like this:

```php
array(
  array(
    '1',
    '2019-10-15',
    'Orientation / Team Building',
    '371',
    '',
    '0',
    '',
  ),
  array(
    '1',
    '2019-10-16',
    'Study Skills',
    '371',
    '',
    '0',
    '',
  ),
);
```

I would like to output one day at a time:

```
$currentMonth = date('F');
$dayOfSchedule = 0;
while ($dayOfSchedule < sizeof($schedule[$currentMonth]){
   echo $schedule[$currentMonth][$dayOfSchedule][2]; //output the class etc.
}
```

and then increment $dayOfSchedule on the day change, but I don't know how to do that.

Any help is much appreciated!

Comment: So you mean you  want to build a proper `$schedule` array with the data you got from the CSV so  the while loop works?

Comment: Or do you simply want to loop through the CSV data?

Comment: Also, which column of your CSV should be `$dayOfSchedule`?

Comment: Sorry, I should have been clearer. I simply want to loop through the array one day at a time. If the user would only upload csv-files that cover every day in the month ,from the first day to the last, I could simply output $schedule[date("F)][date("j")][...], but unfortunately I can't.

Answer (score 1):

You're probably looking for something like this:

```php
<?php

$data = array(
  array(
    1,
    '2019-10-16',
    'Study Skills',
    '371',
    '',
    0,
    '',
  ),
  array(
    1,
    '2019-10-16',
    'Mathematics',
    '371',
    '',
    0,
    '',
  ),
  array(
    1,
    '2019-10-15',
    'Orientation / Team Building',
    371,
    '',
    0,
    '',
  ),
);

// map rows according to the date
$schedule = array_reduce($data, function ($accu, $row) {
  $date = \DateTime::createFromFormat('Y-m-d', $row[1]);
  $accu[$date->format('F')][$date->format('j')][] = $row;
  return $accu;
}, []);

// sort the days and months
ksort($schedule);
array_walk($schedule, function (&$month_schedule) {
  ksort($month_schedule);
});

$today = date('j'); // day of month today
if (isset($schedule[date('F')])) {
  foreach ($schedule[date('F')] as $day => $rows) {
    if ((int) $day >= (int) $today) {
      echo "  Day of Month: $day\n";
      foreach ($rows as $key => $row) {
        echo "    Class({$key}): {$row[2]}\n";
      }
    }
  }
  echo "\n";
}
```

Comment: Thank you! Unfortunately, that is not exactly what I'm looking for. My intention is to show only the information for today. So I would like to have a variable that increments by 1 for every day the class information is output - from 0 until the last day of the month.

Comment: Thanks, yes that is very helpful!  I just don't quite understand how I could output just today's information instead of the information for every day of the month?

Comment: @suuuriam: You may simply `var_dump` the `$schedule` structure and see how may use it your own way. It should not be hard.